# Reg: mongo db wrong output as per query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Am using below query:

```
    db.logins.aggregate([
    { $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:59.000-0400")}}},
    { $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: 
    {$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},

{ $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
])
```

but in output we are getting the records for 18th august also8 also:

```
output  like:
====================
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "HSP",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 108
}

/* 50 */
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "AFC",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 3
}
```

We need only 16 th and 17th data count, any suggestions.

Thanks experts, I tried with suggested modification:
is below query will provide the all the unique counts for Uid from 16th Aug 00:00:00 hours to 17th Aug 23:59   confirm pls can we use below query:

```
 db.logins.aggregate([
    { $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T14:30:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T14:32:00.000-0400")}}},
    { $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
    { $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
    ])



collection below:
========================


{
    "_id" : 55,
    "Uid" : "m955",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.com",
    "Role" : "MGR",
    "event" : "TIMEOUT",
    "timeoutTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:33:13.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T18:33:14.663Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 38,
    "attUid" : "mo41b",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.att.com",
    "agentRole" : "W_TECH",
    "event" : "LOGIN",
    "loginLogoutTime" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:34.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:35.220Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: can you add input documents in your question.

Comment: It is working properly, can you check again, check this working [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5eFjQUUzUk6), i think you are passing wrong dates format in input, this is incorrect format of ISODate for mongo `ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:59.000-0400")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) uses UTC by default. Your $match filters records by dates in -4 timezone. The result you observe is number of logins within these 4 hrs.

Either add timezone to $dateToString or remove timezone from $match conditions depending on your needs.

Comment: HI Experts, any suggestion, how can we write above disk utlization script to monitor disk usage.

Comment: Dear @BhanuPratap please avoid overwriting your OP with unrelated content. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: New question is not able to ask, so asking in old thread thanks Alex.

Comment: It's not how it works. Try to provide some quality answers to earn the privilege to ask questions again.

Comment: @BhanuPratap sorry if I wasn't clear enough Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th for details. Basically there is some heuristic which flags your account. Try to **answer** some questions. If you have experience with Oracle and PL/SQL, check if there are people looking for help with these tags.