# mongo db query data for date mismatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.logins.aggregate([
    { $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:59.000-0400")}}},
    { $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: 
    {$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
    { $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
    ])




but in output we are getting the records for 18th august also:


output  like:
====================
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "HSP",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 108
}

/* 50 */
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "AFC",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 3
```

can i use below for getting complete unique counts from 16th feb 00:00  to 17th feb 23:59 , any suggestions what needs to be modifed in query to get the desired result from 16th feb 00:00 hours to 17th Feb 23:59

```
db.logins.aggregate([
{ $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T14:30:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T14:32:00.000-0400")}}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
{ $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
])




Thanks exprrts, i tried running the query again getting same 18th Aug records also showing in output:

db.logins.aggregate([
{ $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:59.000-0400")}}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: 
{$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
{ $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
])


but in output we are getting the records for 18th august also:


output  like:
====================
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "HSP",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 108
}
```

/* 50 */
{
"Dates" : "2020-08-18",
"ROLE" : "AFC",
"TOTALUSERS" : 3
}

Comment: is this same question that you have already asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508134/reg-mongo-db-wrong-output-as-per-query

Comment: Yes Experts ,I have modified the changes as per timings in above query, any inputs would be great.

Comment: db.logins.aggregate([
{ $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:59.000-0400")}}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$aRole" } , uniqueCount: 
{$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
{ $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
])  triesd running the query same  getting 18th aug records also in output, even -4 in timestamp  provided,  any suggestions.