# mongo db output not showing expected result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get  from logins collection to get all the unique count from 16th Aug to 17th Aug 2020.
but somehow I'm getting in output 18th Aug records count also.

```
db.logins.aggregate([
{ $match:{"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-08-16T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-08-17T23:59:00.000-0400")}}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }},Role: "$Role" } , uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$Uid"}}},
{ $project: { "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "ROLE" : "$_id.Role", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"} }}
])
```

Output like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "FS_MG",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-18",
    "ROLE" : "IS_SE_MG",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 10
}



/* 5 */
{
    "Dates" : "2020-08-17",
    "ROLE" : "TF_SE_TEC",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 1852
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reg: mongo db wrong output as per query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508134/reg-mongo-db-wrong-output-as-per-query)

Comment: No experts, i tried to run the query again but still 18th aug data is showing in output.

Comment: It is not require to add new question everytime you can edit your first question and add your tried. this way no one will look at your question, i have already commented there and already a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63508298/8987128) by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Ans Then try this

```
 db.logins.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        loginLogoutTime: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:
                    "$loginLogoutTime"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        loginLogoutTime: { $in: ['2020-08-16', '2020-08-17'] }
    }
}])
```

And Add your Group / Data in projection it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your query requests the data with the timezone `-0400`.
You need to format the data with the same timezone see [$datetostring doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

By default with the aggregation `$dateToString` the result is displayed in UTC (2020-08-17T23:59:00.000-0400 = 2020-08-18T03:59:00+00:00).

You need to run your query with `$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime", timezone: "-0400" }}`

Comment: Thanks experts, for the answers it works in our env.